# WP Задать переменную в зависимости от значения lang сайта

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня такая задача - необходимо переименовывать значения переменной в зависимости от локализации сайта /

[image: Local]

Приведу пример `<input type="text" placeholder="Enter result">` Как переименовывать фразу "Enter result" в зависимости от выбранного региона без учета суб региона Вот мой пример, но он очень топорный

```
<?php

$loc = $locale;

if($loc === 'en-US'){
    $er = 'Enter result';
}else if(($loc === 'es_ES')||($loc ==='es')){
    $er = 'Ingrese el resultado';
}else if ($loc === 'en-AU'){
    $er = 'Enter result';
}
?>
`<input type="text" placeholder="' . $er . '">`
```

Как сделать так что б не зависимо от того выберерет ли в админке человек британскую или австралийскую локаль английского языка ему отдавался один и тот же текст ? Тут стоит применять регулярки ? Не понимаю как просеять en en-AU en-PH ... ?

Comment: Это делается не так. Все надписи/тексты должны браться из лангпака, а не кода.  См https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/codex/translations

Comment: нужно использовать функционал переводов wp https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/